# Exclude the citations in the list of figures

Tags: pdftex

I am using the below command to print the list of figures. But I would like to exclude the citations in the list of figures, though it should show in pdf.

```
\listoffigures\addcontentsline{toc}{chapters}{\listfigurename}
```

[image]

So I wanted to exclude the citatons in this image above.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This is tricky, because you'd have to exclude the space before them as well. I'd stick to what James suggests in his answer.

Comment: [Remove citation from List of Figures](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/67745)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe that in your figure caption you can include an alternate text for the list of figures.  Don't include the cite in the alternate text.

```
\caption[alternate text]{text}
```