# Remove autocite citation from list of tables

Tags: table-of-contents, citing, footnotes

I'm citing in footnotes using autocite

```
\usepackage[
  backend=biber,
  style=iso-authoryear,
  abbreviate=false,
  autocite=footnote,
  mincitenames=1,
  maxcitenames=4]
  {biblatex}
\bibliography{references}
```

To not show the footnote below the list of tables, I'm citing a table like:

```
\caption[Treiber der Trends und Entwicklungen in der Arbeitswelt]{Treiber der Trends und Entwicklungen in der Arbeitswelt \autocite[5]{rump2017}}
```

(see also [Remove citation from List of Figures](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/67745/remove-citation-from-list-of-figures)). 
As expected, the footnote under the LoT disappears, but the citation also disappears from the page of the table itself. 
[image]
[image]

Any idea how to solve this?

MWEB:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\usepackage[
backend=biber,
style=iso-authoryear,
abbreviate=false,
autocite=footnote,
mincitenames=1,
maxcitenames=4]
{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
    @book{key,
        author = {Author, A.},
        year = {2001},
        title = {Title},
        publisher = {Publisher},
    }
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\listoftables
\newpage

\begin{table}[]
    \caption[Test]{Test \autocite[5]{key}}
    \begin{tabular}{lll}
        1 & 2 & 2
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\raggedright\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.Stackexchange! Can you make a [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407)?

Comment: Are either of these of assistance?: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/84329/105447 or https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/29916/105447

Comment: @samcarter I edited the question by adding a MWEB

Comment: @vincentVega The problem is not related to your list of tables or removing the footnote there, but how to use footnotes in floats - which is tricky.

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10181/35864

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Be careful, the following only works if the table does not float to another page. If it does, you have to manually move `\footcitetext{key}` to a suitable place.

The problem is not related to your list of tables or removing the footnote there, but how to use footnotes in floats - which is tricky. With some manual intervention, you could do something like this:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\usepackage[
backend=biber,
style=iso-authoryear,
abbreviate=false,
autocite=footnote,
mincitenames=1,
maxcitenames=4]
{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
    @book{key,
        author = {Author, A.},
        year = {2001},
        title = {Title},
        publisher = {Publisher},
    }
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\listoftables

\newpage

\begin{table}[htbp]
    \caption[test]{Test  \footnotemark}
    \begin{tabular}{lll}
        1 & 2 & 2
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\footcitetext{key}

\clearpage

\raggedright\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Would it normally not be enough to just use `\footnotemark` without optional argument and let LaTeX increase the counter? There is also the command `\footcitetext` that can be used instead of `\footnotetext{\cite{key}}`

Comment: @moewe You are right as always! Thanks for your comment! And now I go and try to find out why I need the `\addtocounter{footnote} \footnotemark[\thefootnote]` construct in my own document ....