# how to hide the references in list of figures

Tags: table-of-contents, overleaf, back-referencing

first when I didn't use the command `\bibliographystyle{unsrt}` to make my references in order, the references didn't showed up, but after that I used it, the references start to appear from the  list of tables as you see in the picture below, so is there any commande for hide them ?[image: list of tables]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! When you ask an answer here, please don't show pictures of code, it is way more useful to have actual code that others can copy-paste to compile it. Can you try to provide a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/201628) that reproduces the problem? Also, it might not be related to the problem, but on the picture overleaf shows that your code has 15 errors! You should really take care of that.

Comment: @Vincent thank you for your orientations, I'm still begginer at latex also I'm new here! I'mm try to ask a better question

Comment: It might be possible to use `{\let\cite=\@gobble \listoftables}` if \cite isn't expanded before appearing in the lot file.

Comment: See also: [Remove citation from List of Figures](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/67745/134144)

Answer (score 1):

This is a standard question that gets asked many times. Unfortunately I can't pinpoint any of them.

Put citations in the main `\caption` argument but also use the optional argument, without any citation, which is what gets sent to the LoF, LoT.

```
\caption[for the list of]{for the main document with a \cite{...}}
```